# Trailing null character after VARCHAR column

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've been struck on this so long. I have a VARCHAR(30) column in few tables. 
This column will have uuid_short() value and some prefixes. I can not tell its fixed length so I made its length to '30'. The problem is: If the actual length comes to '20', remaining 10 characters are filled with null. What am I doing wrong? How to get rid of this nulls?

```
The content
('23', 'UI-iAs-23913618634441256\0\0\0\0\0\0')
```

Comment: Is it really always a VARCHAR(30) and not a CHAR(30)?

Comment: Data to be stored is variable length. So I choose VARCHAR. 
Why not?

Comment: Just making sure it *is* VARCHAR everywhere. Since if you have CHAR(30) somewhere, this is exactly the result you would get.

Comment: I use VARCHAR everywhere. :)

Comment: In that case you don't have trailing blank spaces! Although the entry above would be truncated at the 30th character (about 6 characters from the end)